# Toggle filter row option disapperaed once language switched in Angular SlickGrid

Tags: angular, slickgrid

I am using Angular Slickgrid in my application and I am facing an issue in the slick grid option. Here I described my scenario. First I have applied Toggle Filter Row option in the right corner. Then I switched the language, now I seen the list of option which available at the right corner. I cannot see the Toggle Filter Row option, its disappeared.

Your sample: https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/localization

I have mentioned the below link which has the screen record clip taken from your samples. Please check and advise. Thanks.
https://www.loom.com/share/58bcd0850ba844cf8140c2d48121a9de

Comment: I suggest that you add code sample, print screen or anything that can help in understanding your question, also I cannot and will not click on any video link because I use work laptop, you should use animated gif instead, I use [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/) for that and it works great. Your question is too short, a good question should always include what you tried (typically code) to show that you did some research before asking your question, people are more willing to help someone who did some prior research.

Comment: I read your question again and I think I understand what you mean now. What you mean is that if you follow these steps: 1-click on "Toggle Filter Row"  2-switch language 3- open grid menu, then the toggle option is gone, is that what you meant? If so, it seems to be a bug, you can open a bug issue in the lib.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug and got fixed in [PR #448](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/pull/448), it will be released in coming weeks.

[image: UG82RuSKHr]

EDIT

This was fixed and available under the new Angular-Slickgrid new [version](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/releases)

Comment: Waiting for it. Update here once it will be released.

Comment: it's now available under the new version `2.18.x`